# Removing YouTube embed from my page

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I have a situation where I am loading a Youtube video into a container. Essentially when the user unfocuses on the input where they've punched in their YouTube URL, it gets wrapped in an iframe an embedded into the specified container.

This part of my code seems to work fine. The problem is with when the user removes their URL from the input. When this happens I need the container to revert to the original state.

The code below that I thought would work doesn't. Neither `.empty()` or `.remove()` seem to remove the iframe and put the original content back in place.

If anyone is able to solve my issue that would be much appreciated.

```
<!-- input html -->
<div class="text-group">
    <input class="text-input js-thumb" type="text" placeholder="URL"  required>
</div>

<!-- container html -->
<div class="content-img-wrapper">
    <div class="content-img-placeholder"></div>
</div>


// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    var thumbFetch = $('.js-thumb');
    thumbFetch.blur(function() {
        if(thumbFetch.length >= 1) {
            $('.content-img-wrapper').html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + thumbFetch.val() + '?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        } else {
            $('.content-img-wrapper').empty();
            $('.content-img-wrapper').html('<div class="content-img-placeholder"></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `var thumbFetch = $('.js-thumb');` an input tag?

Comment: Apologies. I will add the input html now

Comment: `thumbFetch.length >= 1` – you are checking the wrong thing here, the length of the jQuery object `$('.js-thumb')` – that is 1, because you have that input field in the document. You actually want to check the _value_ of that input field at the time the blur event occurs, `thumbFetch.val() !== ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thumbFetch.length` tells you how many dom elements match the jQuery selector. Instead, try `thumbFetch.val().length` for the length of the input value.

What you probably want is:

```
var thumbFetch = $('.js-thumb');
thumbFetch.change(function() {
    if(thumbFetch.val() !== '') {
        $('.content-img-wrapper').html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + thumbFetch.val() + '?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    } else {
        $('.content-img-wrapper').html('<div class="content-img-placeholder"></div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not `>= 1`, but `> 0`, or `.val() !== ''`

Comment: @CBroe Why not `>= 1` over `> 0`, or `.val() !==''`?

Comment: There's a standard way of checking for empty input elements. `val().length >= 1` is less understandable than `.val().length > 0` or `.val() !== ''`. They all work though.

Comment: You’re both right, I don’t know why I said “not”, should’ve said “more readable in my opinion” or sth. like that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @CBroe